# What is this anime about a green-haired robot named Sophie?

Tags: soltyrei

In around 2010, I remember watching an anime that was sort of based in the future after some type of explosion happened.

I think there was a green-haired girl robot thing named Sophie, and she stayed with a man named Ryo, who lost his daughter in the explosion.

It ended with the robot girl going into outer space to save everyone.

What is this anime?

Comment: For SEO purposes, just writing here to say that the two characters are actually **Solty** and **Roy** (not Sophie and Ryo).

Answer (score 6):

You're definitely thinking of [**SoltyRei**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoltyRei).

[image: SoltyRei poster]

There's [Roy Revant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SoltyRei_characters#Roy_Revant) (right), a bounty hunter who lost his daughter in the Blastfall (when a large building exploded).

[Solty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SoltyRei_characters#Solty_Revant) (middle), a *Resemble* (or artificial human), unlike anything the world has seen before...

And finally [Rose Anderson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SoltyRei_characters#Rose_Anderson) (left), a thief who is revealed to be Rita Revant (Roy's daughter), shortly before her death.